# Overriding locale string in Office Add-Ins commands

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins, office-js

I based my work on [this example](https://github.com/jasonjoh/command-demo) for Office add-ins commands. I am trying to have a localized version of the strings displayed in the commands.
Having a look at this [xsd schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt487013(v=office.12).aspx) I inserted the following `<ShortLocaleOverride>` elements in the manifest without success. My Office2016 has been set to french and fr-FR is indeed the displayed language returned by `Office.context.displayLanguage`.

The following XML does not work and 'Add-in EN' is displayed in my Ribbon.

```
<bt:ShortStrings>
    <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="Add-in EN">
        <bt:ShortLocaleOverride Locale="fr-FR" Value="Add-in FR"></bt:ShortLocaleOverride>
     </bt:String>
....
<bt:ShortStrings>
```

What would be the correct way to have my add-in commands strings displayed in french when Outlook is in french?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/mt267547.aspx

```
<bt:ShortStrings>
  <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="Add-in Demo">
    <bt:Override Locale="ar-sa" Value="عرض الوظيفة الإضافية" />
  </bt:String>
  <!-- Other short strings -->
</bt:ShortStrings>
```

This should be an `bt:Override` element, not `bt:ShortLocaleOverride`. I'm not sure if they are case-sensitive or not (note the example uses `ar-sa` instead of `ar-SA`).

Comment: Oups, it seems that I missed this documentation. Thank you for your time!